# Multiple subsequent connected equations exceeding line length

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath

How to break a number of equations like in the following example?

```
\begin{align}
     \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda\\
     \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta
\end{align}
```

Given that both equation lines are too long to fit into one line, how can I break them such that

1. the remainders are right aligned and
2. no further breakage marker is needed.

Note: I read about 20 seemingly similar questions, but most deal with only one line or require additional markup/tags to get the split position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're about, but this seems to fulfill your wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,environ,xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{splitalign}[1][.9\displaywidth]
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_drahnr_mysplit_input_seq { \\ } \BODY
  \seq_clear:N \l_drahnr_mysplit_output_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_drahnr_mysplit_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_drahnr_mysplit_output_seq
     {
      \parbox{#1}{\raggedleft$\displaystyle##1$}
     }
   }
  \begin{align}
  \seq_use:Nn \l_drahnr_mysplit_output_seq { \\[1ex] }
  \end{align}
 }
\seq_new:N \l_drahnr_mysplit_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_drahnr_mysplit_output_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{splitalign}
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda
\\
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta
\end{splitalign}
\lipsum*[3]
\begin{splitalign}[.5\textwidth]
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot
\lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda \cdot \lambda
\\
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot
\beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta \cdot \beta
\end{splitalign}

\end{document}
```

I split the input at `\\`, then package each chunk in a `\parbox` of the stated width (default `0.9\displaywidth`) with right alignment and using inline math mode, where breaks are allowed after binary operation symbols.

[image]

Comment: Does not work exactly well. For `\begin{splitalign}
 \int\limits_0^{\gamma} (1-r)^{\frac{n-6}{2}} \cdot r^3 dr =\\
= \frac{-2}{n+2} \cdot \left(\left[ r^3 \cdot (1-r)^{\frac{n-4}{2}}) \right]_0^{\gamma} - 3 \cdot \frac{-1}{n} \cdot \left(\left[ r^2 \cdot (1-r)^{\frac{n-4}{2}} \right]_0^{\gamma} - 2 \cdot \frac{-1}{n-2} \cdot \left(\left[ r^1 \cdot (1-r)^{\frac{n-4}{2}} \right]_0^{\gamma} - 1 \cdot \left[ \frac{-2}{n-4} \cdot (1-r)^{\frac{n-4}{2}} \right]_0^{\gamma} \right) \right) \right)\\
= \dots
\end{splitalign}` does break properly.

Comment: @drahnr TeX will never split a math formula between `\left` and `\right`. Use `\bigl`, `\bigr` and friends.